# НАПРИМЕР перед перечислением. Двоеточие или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

*Например, на тренировку и с тренировки, за покупками или в кино.*

*Например: на тренировку и с тренировки, за покупками или в кино.*

В каких случаях ставится двоеточие после слова *например*? Только при перечислении?

Comment: Приветствую всех участников. Давно сюда не заглядывала. Интересуюсь: здесь теперь задают вопросы ленивые школьники, которые даже на уроке не в состоянии услышать объяснение учителя или прочитать материал учебника? Раньше на подобные вопросы не отвечали.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно отметить три случая применения слова **"например"**.

1. Вводное слово со значением частных примеров: *А если б я, например, вздумал донести коменданту?* *Можете, например, остановиться в нашем доме.* Также: *Он, в частности, вполне подходит для этой роли.*
2. Вводное слово после обобщающего слова: *К краснолесью относятся породы смолистых деревьев, например: сосна, пихта, ель.*
3. Вводное слово в значении присоединительного союза: *Существует легенда, что Калиостро добывал золото из всех других металлов, например из меди, простым прикосновением руки.*

### Решение

> ...например: на тренировку и с тренировки, за покупками или в кино

В предложении с перечислением обычно присутствует обобщение, и тогда перед однородным рядом ставится двоеточие.

Вводное слово *"например"* или присоединительный союз *"например"* сложно отнести к однородным членам, поэтому запятая в этом случае не применяется (при постановке запятой грамматическая конструкция становится неясной).

Comment: Двоеточие после "например" перед однородными членами стилистически ограничено. В публицистических и художественных текстах его рекомендуют не ставить.

Answer (score 3):

В текстах делового и научного стиля речи при наличии перед однородными членами обобщающего слова после *например* ставится двоеточие:

*Хорошо принялись многие саженцы, например: клен, тополь, акация.*

Но такая пунктуация не характерна для художественных и публицистических текстов. В них уместнее нейтральный вариант расстановки знаков:

*Хорошо принялись многие саженцы, например клен, тополь, акация.*

Однородные перечисления при обобщающем слове относятся к уточняющим членам, поэтому могут отделяться и запятой – необязательно двоеточием.

В данном случае уместнее запятая, так как обобщающего слова в этом предложении нет (если оно, конечно, приведено полностью). К тому же предложение явно публицистического стиля. Если бы эта группа однородных членов с вводным словом входила в состав более распространенного предложения, то запятой бы выделялся весь обособленный оборот:

*Мы предпочитаем везде ходить вместе, например на тренировку и с тренировки, за покупками или в кино.*

Слово *например* связано со следующей пунктуацией:

а) выделяется запятыми как вводное: *Николай Артемьевич любил настойчиво поспорить, например, о том, можно ли человеку в течение всей своей жизни объездить весь земной шар (Т.);*

б) выделяется запятыми вместе с оборотом, в начале или в конце которого находится: *Даже в городах, например в Москве, когда тронется мелководная Москва-река, все её берега и мосты бывают усыпаны народом (Акс.); Вопросом заинтересовались и другие, я например;*

в) требует постановки запятой перед собой и двоеточия после себя, если стоит после обобщающего слова перед перечислением однородных членов предложения: *Некоторые грибы очень ядовиты, например: бледная поганка, сатанинский гриб, мухомор.*