# Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо (–) например, курица,

Tags: пунктуация, тире-или-двоеточие

Уместно ли здесь использование тире?

"Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо – например, курица, свинина, говядина или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо, например: курица, свинина, говядина или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса.

**Этот классический вариант с двоеточием не подходит**, так как после "например" мы получаем **общий однородный ряд** , в то время как по смыслу у нас два варианта: (1) различные виды мяса или (2) сочетания из них:

2) **Тот же неправильный смысл** мы имеем и при постановке одного тире **в предложенном варианте.**

3) Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо – курица, свинина, говядина или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса. **Это правильный вариант, но без вводного слова.**

4) **Вставочные варианты с двумя тире или скобками**

Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо, – например, курица, свинина, говядина –  или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса.

Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо (например, курица, свинина, говядина) или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса.

Comment: Откуда взялась запятая перед тире  в предпоследнем предложении (Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо, – например, курица, свинина, говядина – или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса)? Думаю, это описка.

Answer (score 0):

Несколько раз сталкивался с подобной пунктуацией, но не могу обосновать нормативность тире в данном случае. Перед перечислением после обобщающего слова используется двоеточие. Современные тенденции правописания допускают иногда использование тире вместо двоеточия, но не в этих случаях. С другой стороны, здесь перечисление осложнено наличием "например" и членом с "или" (почему с "или", кстати, а не с "и"?).

Тире бы тут смотрелось, будь оно парным, т.е. если бы вся конструкция, присоединяемая этим "например", не заканчивала бы фразу. А так остаётся только полагать, что тире здесь поставлено по авторским мотивам, для передачи, например, того, что предложение распадается на две части, хотя и такая мотивация крайне удивительна.

По всему по этому я бы рекомендовал написание ***"Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо, например: курица, свинина, говядина или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса"***.

Вот некоторые соображения, объясняющие выбор такой пунктуации.
["Например". Двоеточие или запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33438)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что тире здесь оправдано только в случае пропуска слова "например" - тогда (в отличие от простого перечисления после двоеточия) оно замещает это слово, свидетельствуя о произведённом упрощении:

> Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо – курица, свинина,
>   говядина или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса.

В полном предложении такого же смысла перед "например" нужна запятая.

> Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо, например курица,
>   свинина, говядина или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов
>   мяса

.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, "скелет" этого предложения таков: "Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса". Даны примеры мяса, а не фарша. Вся конструкция с *например* выделяется запятыми, но для более ясного ее выделения я бы добавил тире:

**Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо, например курица, свинина, говядина, — или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса.**

Можно просто выделить двумя тире:

**Для изготовления котлет используется различное мясо — например, курица, свинина, говядина — или же комбинированные фарши из нескольких видов мяса.**

Но мне больше нравится первый вариант. В нем использовано выделение запятыми как более мягкое, а вторая часть (после тире) приобретает присоединительный оттенок.