# "Сцена Агнца и обступивших его оленей"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Есть и иллюстрации к псалмам – например, **сцена Агнца и обступивших
>   его оленей** на перекрёстке четырёх рек означает и Рай, и видение
>   новообращённых (оленей), которые приникают, истомившиеся, к любви и
>   мудрости Божественной, как к роднику.

Сцена - изображающая? отображающая? сцена встречи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть и иллюстрации к псалмам – например, сцена... означает...

1.Иллюстрацией является **сцена**, а не "**сцена... ознаечат**"
2.Знаки препинания при слове "например" ( см.[НАПРИМЕР перед перечислением. Двоеточие или запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33438/%d0%9d%d0%90%d0%9f%d0%a0%d0%98%d0%9c%d0%95%d0%a0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f))

> сцена... означает и Рай, и видение новообращённых(?!)

Вариант правки: **Есть и иллюстрации к псалмам, например сцена, изображающая Агнца и обступивших его оленей и символизирующая и Рай, и видение новообращённых...**

Answer (score 1):

Есть и иллюстрации к псалмам – например,  **Агнец и обступившие его олени** на перекрёстке четырёх рек символизируют (обозначают)  и Рай, и видение новообращённых (оленей), которые приникают, истомившиеся, к любви и мудрости Божественной, как к роднику.