# Обособление "например" и "согласно ему"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

**В сказительстве существуют определенные запреты, которые нарушать не следует, например(,) поверье, что истории можно рассказывать только вечером...**

**Существует запрет на рассказывание сказок днем, согласно ему(,) сказочнице или члену ее семьи грозит кара.**

Нужны ли запятые в скобках?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сказительстве существуют определенные запреты, которые нарушать не следует, **например поверье о том,** что истории можно рассказывать только вечером... Существует запрет на рассказывание сказок днем  **― согласно ему, сказочнице или члену ее семьи грозит кара.**

Вводное слово ***например*** используется в качестве присоединительного союза.

**Тире** в бессоюзном сложном предложении.

***Согласно ему*** ― обособленный оборот с производным предлогом и значением соответствия.

Answer (score 1):

Вот полезная информация — все случаи постановки знаков препинания при слове "например" (даю как ответ, так как ссылка не помещается в комментарии): 
[НАПРИМЕР перед перечислением. Двоеточие или запятая?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/33438/%d0%9d%d0%90%d0%9f%d0%a0%d0%98%d0%9c%d0%95%d0%a0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%94%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f)